# Error on IF ELSE with XML file strtotime

Tags: php, xml

Not sure what I am doing wrong?  I keep getting the follow error...

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in phpsqlajax_genxml.php on
>   line 63

When I remove the `}` I get an invalid `$end`?

Thanks for the help.

```
<?php  

require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php"); 

header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

$filename = "hockey.xml";
$filetime = filemtime("$filename");

if (strtotime("+1 days", $filetime) < time()) {
    $file = file_get_contents('hockey.xml');
    echo $file;
} else {

    // Start XML file, create parent node

    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); 

    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server

    $connection = mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);

    if (!$connection) {
        die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    } 

    // Set the active MySQL database

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    } 

    // Select all the rows in the markers table

    $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1 AND lng != '' order by team asc";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {  
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    } 

    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  
        // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE  
        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
        $newnode->setAttribute("rinksize", $row['rinksize']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("category", $row['category']);
    } 

    echo $dom->saveXML();
    $dom->save("hockey.xml")
}

?>
```

Comment: *Always* consistently format your code (and I suggest four spaces, not two, since it's easier to visually parse). Your code formatting is very important; it allows you to visually inspect for obvious errors in logic and syntax. Just in formatting, I noticed the lack of the `;` at the very end. Your code formatting is important *only* because it's meant for you to *read*.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, not sure what you mean by spaces between lines?

Comment: That's four spaces to begin each statement/line, multiplied by the level between each code block... Indention, in other other words. See how I formatted you code in the question.

Comment: Compare http://pastebin.com/Sm7MQHNz with http://pastebin.com/xhS4fU57 as far as readability and your ability to parse out code blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the semicolon after $dom->save("hockey.xml")

Comment: Stupid, can't believe I missed that.  Anyway, the file is still generating?